# How do I find nth occurance of delimeter in continuous file using python

Tags: python, python-2.6

Input file is continuous and I want to split the nth occurrence of delimiter with new line.

I tried the following:

```
with open ("ip.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        A = line.split("Ç")
        B= ['Ç'.join(x) for x in [A[i:i + 10] for i in xrange(0, len(A), 10)]]
with open ("op.txt","w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("Ç\n".join(s))
```

And I am getting memory error.

How can I avoid it?

Comment: Please edit your question and add full error/exception so that we can see what is going on.

Comment: Am getting error while splitting delimeter memory error

Answer (score 0):

**New answer based on the clarifications in the comments:**

```
def split(text, separator, each):
    if each < 1:
        raise AttributeError('each must be >= 1')

    parts = text.split(separator)

    if len(parts) <= each:
        return [text]

    lines = []
    for idx in range(0, len(parts), each):
        segment = separator.join(parts[idx:idx + each])
        if idx + each < len(parts):
            segment = '%s%s' % (segment, separator)
        lines.append(segment)

    return '\n'.join(lines)


print(split('1¢2¢3¢4¢5¢6¢7¢8¢9¢10¢11¢12¢13¢14¢15¢16¢17¢18¢19¢20¢21¢22', '¢', 10))
```

Which outputs:

```
1¢2¢3¢4¢5¢6¢7¢8¢9¢10¢
11¢12¢13¢14¢15¢16¢17¢18¢19¢20¢
21¢22
```

---

**Old answer:**

I'm not actually sure of the exact result you want, so I'm gonna give a code snippet that returns a two items list: firstly the string part before the split, and secondly the string part after the split. You can easily change this if you want a slightly different result.

```
def split(text, separator, position):
    if position < 1:
        raise AttributeError('position must be >= 1')

    parts = text.split(separator)

    if len(parts) <= position:
        return [text]

    return [separator.join(parts[:position]), separator.join(parts[position:])]
```

Here some examples:

```
>>> split('part0&part1&part2', '&', 1)
['part0', 'part1&part2']

>>> split('part0&part1&part2', '&', 2)
['part0&part1', 'part2']

>>> split('part0&part1&part2', '&', 3)
['part0&part1&part2']

>>> split('part0&part1&part2', '&', 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/paco/Desktop/so/main.py", line 3, in split
    raise AttributeError('position must be >= 1')
AttributeError: position must be >= 1
```

Comment: File is sequence and delimited file I want exactly 10th delimeter after line is separate with new line and again start this same action till end of the file. Now am getting memory error.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. It would be best if you gave some sample input strings and expected output strings.

Comment: Input:2¢88¢m¢ city¢3¢6¢name¢gen¢890¢ ¢ ¢01 56¢ and soon.

Comment: Output:2¢88¢m¢ city¢3¢6¢name¢gen¢890¢ ¢ exactly 10th delimeter after new line

Comment: Rest of the content in another line till 10th delimeter.

Comment: Check my edited answer and accept it if it is what you want.